# Sort CSV data when the number of columns isn't known?

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

Consider a CSV file where I know how the first two columns look like, but not how the rest looks like:

```
Id | DateWithTime | column 3 | ... | column n
```

I want to read such a file, sort it by the `DateWithTime` column and save it. I don't know how many columns the file has, so I can't build a model for it. I only know it at least has the first two columns `Id` and `DateWithTime`. So, how would I access this file with CSVHelper and sort it?

Note: Assume `DateWithTime` can be alphabetically sorted, nothing fancy here. The question is about how to access it, as I can't build a model due to the unknown number of columns.

Note 2: The header might be incomplete, e.g. the header might have 5 columns, but the data might sometimes have 6 columns or more.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps reading as `dynamic` objects would be viable?  https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/get-dynamic-records/

```
void Main()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>();
        var sorted = records.OrderBy(i => DateTime.Parse(i.DateWithTime)).ToList();

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("output.csv"))
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            csv.WriteRecords(records);
        }
    }
}
```

Though the "may be more rows than the header" issue may not work well for this.

Another option may be to read and sort the data as lines without parsing it (though that would be problematic if some of the data is multiple lines).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Meanwhile my circumstances changed and the header is always complete. So dynamic is one option. However, is it possible to mix static typing and dynamic, e.g. can I use my knowledge about the data types of the first two columns `Id` and `DateWithTime`  or do I completely have to go "dynamic"?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe DataTable will be the solution?
You can add as many columns as you need, insert rows, keep datetime data type, rest of columns are plain text, that's not a problem.
DataTable can sort rows.
If the header is incomplete, it may be possible to add a column while reading the file.
Or add more columns to start with than you expect. The column names are irrelevant.

Edited:
Better option can be read using class like:

```
public class Row
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public DateTime DateWithTime {get;set;}
   public string RestOf {get;set;}

}
```

You don't care about columns lenght, sorting with Linq is the easy part